# Load entity framework twice in server side processing, datatable throw error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatable, datatables

i am currently using database with MVC core2.0 to build my application, however, when i try to access to the database twice in the server code, the browser will throw me the error with Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR

the following is my datatable setting in js

```
 settingsInitEmpty = {
            ajax: ({
                url: "/Batch/LoadWithdrawalListData?batch_id=@Context.Request.Query["batchID"].ToString()&search_type=" + search_type + "&value=" + value + "&status=" + status + "&agent=" + agent,
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "json"
            }),
            // ### FOR SERVERSIDE LOADING
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            filter: false,
            orderMulti: false,
            order: [[2, "desc"]],
            columnDefs: [
                { targets: 0, className: 'text-center', orderable: false },
                { targets: 1, className: 'text-center', orderable: false },
                { targets: 2, className: 'text-left' },
                { targets: 3, className: 'text-center' },
                { targets: 4, className: 'text-right' },
                { targets: 5, className: 'text-right' },
                { targets: 6, className: 'text-right' },
                { targets: 7, className: 'text-right' },
                { targets: 8, className: 'text-center' },
                { targets: 9, className: 'text-left' },
                { targets: 10, className: 'text-center' },
                { targets: 11, className: 'text-center'  },
                { targets: 12, className: 'text-center', orderable: false },
            ],
            columns: [
                { data: "id", name: "id", autoWidth: true },
                { data: "name", name: "name", autoWidth: true },
                { data: "amount", name: "amount", autoWidth: true, render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 2, 'US$ ') },
                { data: "xchangeRate", name: "xchangeRate", autoWidth: true },
                { data: "processingFee", name: "processingFee", autoWidth: true, render: function (data, type, row) { if (row.processingFee != null) { return '¥ ' + row.processingFee; }else return '' } },
```

On the server side, the following code is my code

```
  var userAgentList =  _userManager.Users.Where(x=>x.Role == "Agent");
            var draw = Request.Form["draw"].FirstOrDefault();
            var start = Request.Form["start"].FirstOrDefault();
            var length = Request.Form["length"].FirstOrDefault();
            //Find Order Column
            var sortColumn = Request.Form["columns[" + Request.Form["order[0][column]"].FirstOrDefault() + "][name]"].FirstOrDefault();
            var sortColumnDir = Request.Form["order[0][dir]"].FirstOrDefault();

            //var search_type = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Query["search_type"]);
            //var value = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Query["value"]);
            var batch_id = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Query["batch_id"]);
            var search_type = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Query["search_type"]);
            var value = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Query["value"]);
            var status = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Query["status"]);
            var agent =HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Query["agent"]);


            int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
            int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
            int recordsTotal = 0;

            IQueryable<WithdrawalRecords> withdrawalList = _context.WithdrawalRecords;
            //query = query.Where(p => p.product_name.Contains(pageModel.searchList.product_name));

            withdrawalList = withdrawalList.Where(p => p.BatchId.Equals(batch_id));


            //SORT
            if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDir)))
            {
                withdrawalList = withdrawalList.OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDir);
            }
            recordsTotal = withdrawalList.Count();
            var data2 = withdrawalList.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();

            List<string> serial = new List<string>();
            for (int a = 0; a < data2.Count(); a++)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data2[a].SubBatchId))
                {
                    serial.Add(data2[a].SubBatchId);
                }
            }
            _context.SaveChanges();
            var subBatchList = _context.SubBatch.Where(x => serial.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
            for (int a = 0; a < subBatchList.Count(); a++)
            {
                var agentName = userAgentList.Where(x => x.Id == subBatchList[a].AgentId).Single().Name;
                for (int b = 0; b < data2.Count(); b++)
                {
                    if (data2[b].SubBatchId == subBatchList[a].Id)
                    {
                        data2[b].Comment = agentName;
                    }
                }
            }


            var result = Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = data2 });
            return result;
```

OK, now the problem is, when build and debug the code, there is no error, or any exception throw by my controller, as a result, the following result has been returned without show any result.

[image]

Please see my c# code, if i comment out the second tolist() function which get data from db, whole function is fine, the error only occur when i have 2 tolist function in the c# function

Comment: And what happens on server side? Place a breakpoint in your code and step trough, to see if any exception occures. Debugging this from client side is hardly possible. The most you can do is to inspect network traffic.

Comment: server side no problem, whole line work fine, there is no exception in the controller part, only error occur on the frontend , but if i comment out the 2nd tolist function it work fine

Comment: are you sure you are running your server side code in debug mode? or are you trying to debug in the release mode?

Comment: Have you tried with other browsers ? just check whether the same result is getting when u try with other browsers as well

Comment: what is the error code of the reponse

Comment: guys, there is no error which throw from server side, the function is able to completely execute. It only occur when get back data to the datatable, and the error is display in the console which i already attached in the picture above

Comment: As this is only a portion of your code, might happen that some asnyc code is executed without live context, like the object is disposed. For example: where comes `_context` variable from? as it is strictly related to your issue.